# No matching signature for operator > for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY > ANY at BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am calculating  the number of rating score for each of the user in bigquery. But, my rating column in table is in string data type. So, when I run my query, it returns the error, which i believe is because of the data types:

```
 No matching signature for operator > for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: ANY > ANY
```

The pseudocode is like:
if rating < 0 , then count,
if rating >10 ,then count

```
SELECT 
    User_ID, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN Rating < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rating_below_1, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Rating > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rating_above_10 
FROM
    table
GROUP BY User_ID;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `countif()`:

```
SELECT User_ID, 
       COUNTIF(Rating < '0') AS rating_below_1, 
       COUNTIF(Rating > '10') as rating_above_10 
FROM table
GROUP BY User_ID;
```

You can also use `safe_cast()`:

```
SELECT User_ID, 
       COUNTIF(SAFE_CAST(Rating as INT64) < 0) AS rating_below_1, 
       COUNTIF(SAFE_CAST(Rating as INT64) > 10) as rating_above_10 
FROM table
GROUP BY User_ID;
```